# Remove email from registration page

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to modify the registration so that no need for the email. we will only ask for Username and password. I am using WordPress and a plugin called ultimate membership pro to manage membership. this plugin is responsible for the registration page. Could anyone here help with this?

Comment: Email addresses are a major part of the wordpress cms including communications to any changes of account details. Why would you want to do this? Furthermore, you should show attempts of your code so the community can respond with solutions. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin to create the registration page.

[plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/)